# fix icon direction when change language

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

i use the native base components. when use the icon in item area by input, when change language system icon direction change. there is way to fix icon direction ?

```
    <View style={LoginStyle.MainViewS}>
        <View style={LoginStyle.DataView}>
            <Item style={LoginStyle.ItemS}  >
                <Input placeholder="username" style={LoginStyle.InputS} />
            </Item >
            <Item style={LoginStyle.ItemS}  >
                <Icon name='checkmark-circle' style={{ color: 'green', }} />
                <Input placeholder="password" style={LoginStyle.InputS} />
            </Item>

            <TouchableOpacity style={LoginStyle.TouchableS} onPress={() => Actions.register()} >
                <Text style={LoginStyle.TouchableTS} >register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={LoginStyle.TouchableS} onPress={() => Actions.forgetpass()} >
                <Text style={LoginStyle.TouchableTS}>forgetpass</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={LoginStyle.TouchableBS} onPress={() => Actions.index()}>
                <Text style={LoginStyle.ToucableBTS}>login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

What is the style of LoginStyle.InputS and LoginStyle.ItemS?

Try adding:

```
{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0 }
```

to the LoginStyle.InputS

```
<Item style={LoginStyle.ItemS}  >
            <Icon name='checkmark-circle' style={{ color: 'green', }} />
            <Input placeholder="password" style={{...LoginStyle.InputS, position:'absolute', top:0, right:0}} />
        </Item>
```

Comment: thnks for answer InputS: {
        paddingRight: 10,
        textAlign: 'right',
        fontFamily: 'IRANSansMobile',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#8D8D8D'
    },
    ItemS: {
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderRightWidth: 1,
        borderLeftWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#F3F3F3",
        height:40,
        borderRadius: 15,
        marginTop: 15
    },